# Problems with Java app at runtime due to class references from required .class files unresolved

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, classpath, maven-plugin

VS Code with Java plugins, using Maven POMs for a test application that uses classes in a jar that reference classes in another jar results in runtime error saying that the class referenced from the required .class file cannot be resolved. Both jars are installed to the local maven repository. All dependencies are specified in their respective POMs. This happens when running from within VSCode using a launch (without a launch.json file). Shouldn't the classpath at runtime be able to pick up the recursive dependencies?

Comment: What happens when you just run `mvn verify` from a terminal instead of using VS Code/launch.json?

Comment: man verify runs without reporting any problems.

Comment: It looks like, if you have multiple folders in your VS Code project, where each builds to a jar which gets copied to a local maven repository which is used at runtime to satisfy the external references, this completely messes up the Java plugins unless you Restart Extension Host. Having figured out this workflow I am able to be productive in this environment. Before that, when trying to compile other part of the project, the compilation step would fail due to missing classes (defined in one of the other sub-projects if you will) which had been updated. The whole environment becomes unusable.

Comment: We can't get more detailed information to reproduce this issue, and if it's verified as a bug, it's important for engineers to fix, then users can achieve better experience. Would you mind sharing your project in OneDrive or GitHub if it's convenient?

Comment: Unfortunately, the client does not allow the project to be shared. In the meantime, I have moved to the community edition of IntelliJ which comes with its own issues, but seems to be rather better integrated with VCS (git) and does not exhibit this issue. There is also no guarantee that if you were to reproduce the circumstances, which is that there are 3 jars and one application dependent upon them in a cascade fashion, each a different module in a VS Code project, you would see the same behavior. Sorry I can't help.

Comment: It's okay, If you wanna switch back to VS Code, Welcome! Happy Coding:)